# Exact difference between self::__construct() and new self()

Tags: php, class, constructor, instance

Can you tell me the exact difference between `return self::__construct()` and `return new self()`?

It seems one can actually return a `self::__construct()` from a `__construct()` call when the object is created, returning the object itself as if the first `__construct()` was never even called.

Comment: The exact difference is that you'll get a fatal error with `self::__construct()` because constructor is implied to be a static one - which php doesn't have (at least not my 5.3.10 that I use). `new self()` will correctly create the object. Of course, a lot of this depends on the context also, such as where are you invoking those statements from.

Comment: @N.B. [No fatal error in 5.2.5](http://codepad.org/WBo164MK)... and your argument falls apart anyway, when you consider that you can legitimately do `parent::__construct()`...

Comment: @DaveRandom - I did say "it depends on context", didn't I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is best illustrated in code:

```
class MyClass {

   public $arg;

   public function __construct ($arg = NULL) {
     if ($arg !== NULL) $this->arg = $arg;
     return $this->arg;
   }

   public function returnThisConstruct () {
     return $this->__construct();
   }

   public function returnSelfConstruct () {
     return self::__construct();
   }

   public function returnNewSelf () {
     return new self();
   }

}

$obj = new MyClass('Hello!');
var_dump($obj);
/*
  object(MyClass)#1 (1) {
    ["arg"]=>
    string(6) "Hello!"
  }
*/

var_dump($obj->returnThisConstruct());
/*
  string(6) "Hello!"
*/

var_dump($obj->returnNewSelf());
/*
  object(MyClass)#2 (1) {
    ["arg"]=>
    NULL
  }
*/

var_dump($obj->returnSelfConstruct());
/*
  string(6) "Hello!"
*/
```

`return self::__construct()` returns the *value* returned by the objects `__construct` method. It also runs the code in the constructor again. When called from the classes `__construct` method itself, returning `self::__construct()` will actually return the constructed class itself as the the method would normally do.

`return new self();` returns *a new instance* of the calling object's class.

Comment: @DaveRandom I thought a php constructor is supposed to only return the object he creates, not a value.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that `new self()` would create a new instance of the class while `self::__construct ()`only calls the classes `__construct` method.

Comment: And `__construct` methods don't usually have return values.

Comment: @Rocket - `__construct` always has a return value - the object created.

Comment: @N.B. That's not the case, [is it](http://codepad.org/nMRedKBa)? Construct does not return the instance of the class, it is called during instantiation and returns NULL. In practice, at least.

Comment: @N.B.: Not exactly.  When doing `new class`, the return value of `__construct` is ignored, and the object is returned.  But, when calling `__construct` like a normal function, it does just that.  It acts like a function and returns whatever it returns.  http://ideone.com/IZSi8

Comment: `__construct` should always return `void`. It's the `new` operator that returns an instance of the class, not the constructor.

Comment: It's also actually quite weird to call the constructor of an object after it has been constructed. Some languages doesn't even allow it. You probably just should separate the re-usable constructor logic in another method, e.g.: `init()`.

Comment: @netcoder One wouldn't normally call a constructor after the class has been constructed. It seems however possible to re-construct while the class is being constructed, something that may come in handy in the future.